What is Process.Env.3DVPATH, Why Can't I Find it in Google nor in my Code, Why does it Error after generating Shopify Extension?
I'm new to Shopify and creating app and extensions. I'm trying to create the App template, and than the App Extension template. I can create an app template and run it fine, but when I generate a Extension with the npm run generate extension, it errors with this error when I try to run dev.
Context failed with 1 error:                                                │
│  error: The define key "process.env.3DVPATH" contains invalid identifier     │
│  "3DVPATH"
                                                                             │
│  Context failed with 1 error:                                                │
│  error: The define key "process.env.3DVPATH" contains invalid identifier     │
│  "3DVPATH"                                                                   │
│                                                                              │
│  To investigate the issue, examine this stack trace:                         │
│    at failureErrorWithLog (esbuild/lib/main.js:1650)                         │
│      let error = new Error(text);                                            │
│    at (esbuild/lib/main.js:1091)                                             │
│      return callback(failureErrorWithLog("Context failed", response.errors,  │
│       response.warnings), null);                                             │
│    at <computed> (esbuild/lib/main.js:703)                                   │
│      callback(error, response);                                              │
│    at handleIncomingPacket (esbuild/lib/main.js:763)                         │
│      callback(null, packet.value);                                           │
│    at readFromStdout (esbuild/lib/main.js:679)                               │
│      handleIncomingPacket(stdout.subarray(offset, offset + length));         │
│    at emit (node:events:519)                                                 │
│    at emit (node:domain:488)                                                 │
│    at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:559)                          │
│    at readableAddChunkPushByteMode (node:internal/streams/readable:510)      │
│    at push (node:internal/streams/readable:390)                              │
│

I cant find anything about a 3dVpath on google, nor can I find any occurrences of it in my code itself. What gives? How can I fix something I can't get any information about?

If it is an error in Shopify provided code, ask them on the Github issues for the repo with the code you're using. SO here is not specialized in these kinds of errors like Shopify is.
